# Built-in keyboard prints gibberish but external USB keyboard works fine

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard

I have a Macbook Pro 2.3GHz Intel Core i5 running OSX 10.9.5. After my mac went to sleep the built-in keyboard didn't seem to be working properly. It was printing characters like: åß∂ƒ©˙∆˚¬œ∑´®†¥¨ˆøπΩ≈ç√∫˜µ≤≥, which after I checked later look like the normal keyboard characters when holding the options button. I had the options button disabled in the first place.

Things I tried:

- Keyboard viewer works the exact same way with the built-in keyboard, which makes me think that it may not be a HW issue. I pressing for example button a on the virtual keyboard and I get å.
- I activated sticky keys to make sure that the option button wasn't stuck or something. It was fine.
- I plugged a USB keyboard which works fine (phew!).

I was thinking to upgrade to Mavericks and hopefully this will solve the problem but any other ideas or suggestions will be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you unable to upgrade to Yosemite?

Comment: Is is possible the problem is purely mechanical, and a speck of cruft is shorting out one or both Option key mechanisms below the keycap. You might want to try a blast of pressurized 'air' around both Option keys. Similarly, you might want to try giving each Option key a number of harder-than-usual raps with a finger tip to try to dislodge (and in the case of crumbs) pulverize the offending [cruft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cruft).

Comment: Thanks @IconDaemon, I'll try these. brettf, my bad, I was thinking to upgrade to Yosemite not Mavericks (yes there shouldn't be any problem)

Comment: It is hard to imagine any software issue which would let the usb keyboard work fine when the other does not.  Physical damage to the internal keyboard is most likely.